# Show/hide link on responsive image

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink, responsive

I would like to know how to show or hide an image link depending on the browser´s width. For example, on a desktop browser don´t show the link, and show it only on smartphones.

I have found the first approach which could be adding a css class:

```
 .nolink {pointer-events: none;
          cursor: default;}
```

On each *@media screen* which the link should not be shown.

But do you know if there is another way to do this, instead of hiding the link in each of the @media screen, just adding it on the smallest width only once?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use Bootstrap? They already have predefined classes like hidden-xs(won't show on mobile devices), Hidden-lg etc.

Answer (score 1):

You set is by default as text and change it to link just for mobile.

```
.nolink {
       pointer-events: none;
       cursor: default;
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {


.nolink {
    /* Change back to default link style */
}
```

}